# Can I add ESlint rule about indent on empty lines?

Tags: typescript, intellij-idea, eslint

[image]

I'm using 2 spaces for indentation and I want to keep it also no empty lines. Currently ESLint shows warning message **Delete '··' (prettier/prettier)** if there is an indent.

How can I add a rule disables warning about indent on empty lines?

Comment: Does 'Indent on empty lines' make any sense?

Comment: Yes. Intellij has similar option "Keep indents on empty lines"

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could use the plugin [indent-empty-lines](https://www.npmjs.com/package/eslint-plugin-indent-empty-lines) to enforce indentation on empty lines.

The rule `indent-empty-lines` enforces an indentation of 2 spaces by default.

If you need to configure this for a different number of spaces, e.g. 4, here is an example of the ESLint configuration:

```json
"rules": {
  "indent-empty-lines/indent-empty-lines": [ "error", 4]
}
```

More information about the configuration [here](https://github.com/funmaker/eslint-plugin-indent-empty-lines/blob/master/docs/rules/indent-empty-lines.md).